# What's the best server/client combo to remote into your Mac (10.6) from a windows machine?

Tags: software-recommendation, snow-leopard, remote-desktop

I have a Mac OS X 10.6 computer at home, which I like to remote into from my work laptop from time to time. I've tried using RealVNC and UltraVNC with the built-in VNC client, but I can't get them to accept the adaptive compression, so I can either do

1. 8-bit color that is low bandwidth
2. Full color that takes up too much bandwidth for my home's upload speed

Is there a VNC client that supports the adaptive compression on the built-in vnc server for Mac OS X? Some other things I have tried are

1. Using custom VNC server (Vine Server) to get higher color with acceptable bandwith
2. Logmein.com - which seems to have it's own adaptive compression, but is only free for use w/one computer

Comment: Logmein.com lets you use more than one computer with the free license. You can’t transfer files (among other things) but I’m sure you can add more than one computer to your account. Mine is free and I have three.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/).

Like Logmein.com, it is a full software and one based one Mac OS X vnc.

By the way, it also works from an iPad or an iPhone or from a web browser under Windows.

Comment: I've tried all softwares mentioned here so far. TeamViewer is great but I prefer logmein. Both are great, it's just a matter of taste I suppose. At least on the free versions.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps see what http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ can do for you? i'm running it to share out a single monitor out of three, to vnc clients on other platforms that don't support apple's monitor selection extensions or whatever it's called to make that work in mac-to-mac Screen Sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I haven't tried, but [Leo Laporte](http://twit.tv) loves: [GoToMyPC](http://www.gotomypc.com/).

If you're going to try it, be sure to get a discount coupon somewhere.

And here's a good place to look for [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/teamviewer/).

Answer (score -2):

Here is the software we use in our company (Windows): [Radmin](http://www.radmin.com)
Highly recommend. Not sure they have MAC version but my colleagues say they used it on MAC.

Comment: This software does not work on Mac.